# What hash function used in dictionary (hash_table)?

Tags: c++, hash, dictionary, hashtable, hash-function

I'm writting interpreter of language.
There is problem: I want to create type-dictionary, where you can put value of any type by index, that value of any type (simple[int,float,string] or complex[list,array,dictionary] of simple types or of complex of simple types ...). That is the same like in python-lang.
What algorithm of hash-function should I use?

For strings there are many examples of hashes - the simplest: sum of all characters multiplied by 31, divided by HASH_SIZE, that simple number.

But for DIFFERENT TYPES, I think, It must be more complicated algorithm.
I find SHA256, but don't know, how use "unsigned char[32]" result type for adressing in hash-table - it is much more than RAM in computer.
thank you.

Comment: The SHA family of hashes are *cryptographic* hashes. They are unsuitable in a hash table implementation.

Comment: Actually, in Python you can't store lists, arrays or dictionaries in a hash table -- you can store complex objects, but they have to be immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hash tables in C++11, newest C++ standard - std::unordered_map, std::unordered_set.

EDIT:

Since every type has different distribution, usually every type has its own hash function. This is how it's done in Java (.hashCode() method inherited from Object), C#, C++11 and many other implementations.

EDIT2:

Typical hash function does two things:

1.) Create object representation in a natural number. (this is what .hashCode() in Java does)
For example - string "CAT" can be transformed to:

```
67 * 256^2 + 65 * 256^1 + 84 = 4407636
```

2.) Map this number to position in array.
One of the way to do this is:

```
integer_part(fractional_part(k*4407636)*m)
```

Where k is a constant (Donald Knuth in his book Art of Programming recommends (sqrt(5)+1)/2), m is size of your hash table and fractional_part and integer_part (obviously) calculate fractional part and integer part of real number.

In your hash table implementation, you need to handle collisions, especially when there are much more possible keys than size of your hash table.

EDIT3:

I read more on the subject, and it looks like 
    67 * 256^2 + 65 * 256^1 + 84 = 4407636
is really bad way to do hash_code. This is because, "somethingAAAAAABC" and "AAAAAABC" give exactly the same hash code.

Comment: Trees are used in STL. But I want emplement dictionary by myself. Do you mean, I should use trees instead of hash_table?

Comment: No no no, there are trees in STL, but the newest version of C++ standard adds hash tables - note there are maps (trees) and unordered_maps (hash tables).

Comment: I have no objects/classes - only simple types and containers. I need invent exact hash_function for containers. So from edit I can understand, I can't find exact algorithm of hash in unordered_map, because who writes class, writes it. Or they have one for vectors,lists, ... ?

Comment: Yes. Most hash tables implementation delegate creating hash function to someone else - in Java's example, class author. Since I wrongly assumed that this question is about "gimme teh hash function", I will soon edit my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a common approach is to define the hash function as a method belonging to the type.
That way you can call different algorithms for different types through a common API.

That ,of course, entails that you define wrapper classes for every baisc "c type" that you want to use in your interpreter.

Comment: ok, it is possible to code. But what hash_function must I use for dictionary_type, when I put it in dictionary - it is sum of hashes of elements in that? What sum_function should I take?

Comment: It isn't safe to put a dictionary within another. Since dictionaries may chage their content (and therefre their hash values), the lookup will break.

Comment: It sound mad. Hash_function execute of dictionary, that is index (I don't know when it need, but I think do so). You can't change index, only value by found index. a = dict[{1,"2"}] + 7;